# Multiple Properties and Methods using MEF

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mef

I am trying to implment a plugin framework using MEF and I have an interface

```
public interface IPlugin
{
   string SomeProperty {get;set;}
   IList<string> DoSomething(string somevalue);
}
```

I was thinking of doing an implementation which does Import Many

```
public class MainContainer : IPlugin
{
    public string _name;

    public MainContianer(){

    }
    public MainContainer(string name){
       _name = name;
    }

    [ImportMany]
    List<Lazy<IPlugin, string>> plugins;

    string SomeProperty { get { 
       var plugin  = plugins.Where(a => a.Metadata.Equals(_name)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (plugin  != null) {
                return plugin.Value.SomeProperty;
            }
            throw new CustomException();
    } }

    List<string> DoSomething(string value){
        var plugin  = plugins.Where(a => a.Metadata.Equals(_name)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (plugin  != null) {
                return plugin.Value.DoSomething(value);
            }
            throw new CustomException();
    }
}
```

My Question is that Is there a better way to the implement this rather then me writing the same block for each property and method.

```
var plugin  = plugins.Where(a => a.Metadata.Equals(_name)).FirstOrDefault();
if (plugin  != null) {
   return plugin.Value.xxx
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis, the code I posted is just to give an idea on what i was trying to achieve, Its not compile ready code anyway, Help would be appreciated if you point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your sample doesn't make any sense. Why filter through the plugings everytime when you never seem to change _name. Fix your code and bring it close to what you are trying to achieve and then people will be able to help.

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis, I double checked the code and it does compile, so i m close to what i want to do, i cannot paste the code directly from my project, so i have renamed the names but it still works, additionally the user will be given option on which to choose, and based on the users selection i want the select the right plugin to use

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis had changed _name pubilc to private while copy, paste, question updated to reflect same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at all wrong. I have updated my code, the Calculator Example pushed me in the wrong direction.

```
public class MainContainer
{
    private CompositionContainer _container;

    [ImportMany]
    public IEnumerable<IPlugin> Plugins;

    public AdapterProvider(string pluginpath)
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(pluginpath));
        _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        _container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}
```

is enough,

Moderators can close this as an invalid question.